# Fill transparent image with background color

Tags: html, css

I've a transparent image and want to fill with some color as a background. Here are images :
[image]

And After fill with red color:
[image]
I want to make only car's background  red, not square.  This is my css :

```
 #loader-img{
 background:red;
}
```

This is whole html :

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Loader</title>
    <style>
        #loader-back{
            position:absolute;
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
            background : url('../content/img/loader-background.png');
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
        }
        #loader-img{
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;  
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            -webkit-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
            background:red;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="loader-back">
        <img src="~/content/img/loader.png" id="loader-img" />

    </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've update question

Comment: Not possible with CSS. You can't make **part** of an image do anything. You'd need 2 separate images ..or an SVG with distinct parts.

Answer (score 0):

having read at your question here is the code for you,  to change the background colour you can change the colour gold to any colour you want

```html
<img src="https://www.pinclipart.com/picdir/big/18-187351_laser-clipart.png" style="background-color:gold;">
```